# How to properly resize canvas according to screen size? Javascript (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, p5.js, mouse-coordinates

So, as the question says I need to resize the canvas according to screen size. However the thing is that that's not it. I also need to have the mouse coordinates updated proportionally. Seems like I made a fatal mistake of not considering screen sizes from the start since this is my first proper game. I made the game on basis of my 1080p screen. Things like positioning stuff and checking mouse coordinates are all based on a 1920x1080 canvas. Please help!

Github links:

1. Main game, will work but size will depend on your screen: https://proqbr.github.io/powerdown/
2. all the files(only 15MB in case you'd like to see by downloading): https://github.com/proqbr/powerdown
3. sketch.js (pretty much main file regarding this): https://github.com/proqbr/powerdown/blob/master/sketch.js

Main thing is in sketch.js, On **lines 260-263** are some createCanvas lines in `function setup()`, the uncommented one is `createCanvas(1920,1080);` as it's what i was working with. And on **lines 302-314** are a bunch of camera.zoom lines, uncommented one is `camera.zoom = 1;` since on my screen there was no required zoom for the main menu.

Line 352 onwards is some code on knowing where the player clicked, the problem is this. I do know how to make the canvas's contents look properly resized on all screens by using `windowWidth` & `windowHeight` however it's the incorrect mouse coordinates which causes the problem. It would be great if someone could help.

In case there's some problem with the game on your side, here's a quick second video how the game menu works, although it's pretty straightforward anyways: https://youtu.be/eZZw5CmOXEE

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy fix... you have to refactor your code to update proportionally when resizing

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Well that's what it seems like... But i'm pretty sure like if i like maybe multiply the mouse coordinates by some value it would work alright, but i'm unable to think of something like that. if   you could tell something of that sort even that would be great help. like something like multiplying by windowWidth/1920 or something of that sort but i just cant figure it out

Comment: The mouse coords are just the tip of the iceberg, you got hardcoded values all over the place: https://github.com/proqbr/powerdown/blob/master/sketch.js#L268-L275

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Actually many values will remain as they are, so if I can deal with the mouse coords that would be enough. I've tested the main game too it works completely fine apart from some text alignment, which will probably get fixed in a similar way to the mouse coords.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda okay so i did change the values and stuff and made it so that on my screen(1920x1080) it works perfect no matter what the window size is like square, full screen, retangular. BUT it still doesnt work for other screens and I have no clue why

Comment: Do you need to keep the aspect ratio of the screen?

Comment: @Bagel03 actually I figured out a way to do it. I am sorry for taking your time, I shall delete this question in today's time.

Comment: No, leave it up it's fine

Comment: Post your answer so other people might find it

Comment: @Bagel03 ah okay, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. For some values like when testing if `mouseX >= 720` I had to edit it to `mouseX >= 785*windowWidth/1920`.

For one translate that I had used, `translate(95,525)`, I had to modify it a little more and this was the one that properly worked `translate(displayWidth/2-865*(windowWidth)/1920,displayHeight/2-15*(windowHeight)/1080);`

As for screen resizing this worked fine:

```
function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  if(windowHeight > windowWidth){
    factor = windowHeight;
    factdiv = 1080;
  }else{
    factor = windowWidth;
    factdiv = 1920;
  }
}
```

I had to mess around with these to figure out a decent solution

1. canvas dimensions i.e. **`1920, 1080`**
2. **`windowWidth, windowHeight`**
3. and also **`displayWidth, displayHeight`**

I have also updated the same in the repository so you can see the final outcome from here: https://proqbr.github.io/powerdown/